# Submenu revealed only on some pages in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I am using `iron-router` in Meteor.

On most of my pages I use a template

```
<template name="layout">
  <div class="navbar">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
</template>
```

but some of my pages are specific to a specific project. So when the user has selected a project I want both the top/main navbar and a sidebar on the left. From the sidebar on the left, the user is able to navigate to project detail pages such as images, users assigned, etc.

Right now I can accomplish this by creating another layout template `layoutProject` and with `iron-router` I set `layoutTemplate` on those routes related to a project detail page. Besides, I have to set the project id in `data` on all those pages.

Can this be done in more neat? How is this normally done? I have looked at `iron-router`'s examples about dynamic layouts but there's nothing I can use.

I guess it's a quite common problem as the case is seen on most pages, i.e. when seeing an user's profile on Facebook, there is a submenu, letting the user choose to see timeline, about, friends, photos, etc. It's actually the same functionality I need. The way I do it now with two separate layouts seems stupid and non-DRY.

Comment: Use a route controller. https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-controllers Look at their examples for specifying certain `layoutTemplates` for certain routes based on the controller.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have an `ApplicationController` and a `ProjectController`. In the main layout defined in `layoutTemplate` in `ApplicationController`, I have created a navbar. This navbar should be present on all pages. In the `ProjectController`, I can only override `layoutTemplate` but I just want the same effect as on Facebook profile pages, having a different 'main container layout' but preserve the navbar and other elements. Should I use `yieldTemplates`?

Comment: or should I use `action: function() { return this.render("template", { to: "region" }); }`